# Can I carry a mercury-vapor quartz lamp on a flight from Moscow to Sydney?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, qatar-airways

I would like to bring to Australia a quartz lamp for medical reasons (personal use). Flight Moscow-Sydney via Doha with Qatar airlines. Is there anything stopping me doing so and is it best in check or cabin luggage? As far as I understand, the following may be the problem:

- customs at DME Moscow- looks like they do not care as I have read on their website
- airline- not too sure... On one hand it says mercury is prohibited in check in, on another- one can contact airline to arrange for medical equipment- if I am to do that, what is the process? https://www.qatarairways.com/en/baggage/restricted.html
- Australia customs- nothing to do with lamps, but do they worry about devices been certified for Australia?

Answer (score 2):

So after studying the prohibited substances list from airlines and various customs documents I came to a conclusion that a mercury vapor quartz lamp is safe to take on flight - it does not contain mercury in a form of metal, it is a gas. It has safely arrived in the check in luggage.